# h2o: 'null', caused by java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: r, glm, h2o

When fitting a poisson GLM to a dataset - I receive this error code (Error: DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321: 'null', caused by java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException) and am stumped about why this is happening.  I am posting a reproducible example below with a toy dataset that is broadly similar to my dataset and the arguments I am using:

```
df <- data.frame(count = c(512,1025,234,324),gene = c("gene_1","gene_2","gene_1","gene_2"),factor = c(1,2,3,4),factor_2 = c("a","b","c","d"),bound = c("bound","unbound","bound","unbound"))
df <- as.h2o(df)
intx_terms_suppress <- c("factor_2.a","factor_2.b","factor_2.c","factor_2.d","bound.bound","bound.unbound")
constraints <- data.frame(names=intx_terms_suppress, 
                      lower_bounds=0, 
                      upper_bounds=0, 
                      beta_given=0)
y <- 1
train <- c("gene","factor","factor_2","bound")
interactions <- list(c("factor_2", "bound"))
df[,1] <- as.numeric(df[,1])
df[,2:5] <- as.factor(df[,2:5])
fit <- h2o.glm(y = y, x = train, training_frame = df, family = "poisson", standardize = FALSE, interaction_pairs = interactions, beta_constraints = constraints)
```

I appreciate any help anyone might have. And thank you!

Edit: Some more info.  This is my session info:

```
H2O cluster uptime:         2 seconds 363 milliseconds 
H2O cluster timezone:       America/New_York 
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
H2O cluster version:        3.18.0.4 
H2O cluster version age:    17 days  
H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_ra2816_ywt950 
H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
H2O cluster total memory:   444.44 GB 
H2O cluster total cores:    24 
H2O cluster allowed cores:  24 
H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
H2O Connection port:        54321 
H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4 
R Version:                  R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
```

Comment: Your code gives a different error : `unused argument (interaction_pairs = interactions)`

Comment: What version of H2O are you running?  This is on 3.18.0.4.  Sorry for not specifying.  edit: I believe you're getting that error because it's a recently added feature.